# Glassfish 3 EJB3 rmi example

Tags: ejb-3.0, rmi, glassfish-3

Can someone please provide me or link for sample project with standard java rmi capabilities. I wish to deploy it in Glassfish 3 and I have just about tried everything to get a simple project running, but Glassfish does not register my objects. I see that the there is a standard JMX RMI registered on statrup on port 8686 for glassfish. I haven't found any tutorials or examples on this that work. If possible in JAR archive, simple hello world which I can call externally.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok basically it came down to the following:
Created simple main class within the EJB project.
Stating the class should be fired upon startup of the war from the manifest does not work.
Added the annotation @Startup right above my class declaration.
Added the annotation @PostConstruct above my main method, this invoked my method at start up and registered the RMI service.